# Joining 3 tables

Tags: sql

It's late, and my head hurts, so I would appreciate a little help.

I have 3 tables called; **task, users, comments**

In the comments table I have 2 columns called `user_id` and `task_id`.

The main feature here, is that I can click on a task, and then get all of the comments for that task. And so far that is working with this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM comments JOIN task where task.id=task_id
```

I can easily print out my result, and see all of the comments for the selected task. However, I can only see the id of the user belonging to the task.

I'm missing the connection to my users table and displaying the username where the user_id = to the id of the user, instead of just the id, so I want to show username instead of user id.

I've tried something like this, which didn't work:

```
SELECT comments.*, users.username, 
FROM comments, users 
WHERE users.id = user_id  
JOIN task where task.id=task_id
```

Comment: you are missing the `ON` clause in your join, ON clause specifies on what condition you are joining tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample query

```
SELECT comments.*, users.username, 
FROM comments C INNER JOIN task t ON C.task_id=t.task_id 
INNER JOIN users U on  C.user_id = u.user_id    
WHERE t.task_id = @task_id  //(this is variable, pass your task value here)
```